# MVC RedirectPermanent to another domain ends in infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-301

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong here. I Would expect it to redirect me to http:\www.google.com but instead I end up in a loop.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {  
           var redirecturl = string.Format("http:\\www.google.com");
           return RedirectPermanent(redirecturl);
        }
```

Just if you need it, here is my Routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{*url}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I end up with an url like this http://localhost:20000/google.com and an error `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):`

This is a small example I created, I want to end up with a small mvc site, that responce to all url, create a log entry and then do a permanent redirect to another domain (301).

Comment: It should be `http://` not `http:\\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirect to http://www.google.com  not http:\www.google.com
as you can see the first is a link while the second isn't